# ISC-DHCPD failover, Modifying host definitions via OMAPI

Tags: dhcp, failover, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

**Background:** I'm working on replacing my single DHCP server with 2 in a failover configuration. When I do a DHCP request I see the lease is created in both dhcpd.leases files on each server. However, I also use a script that add, deletes, and modifies host definitions via OMAPI. I notice when I make a modification on one server, it is **not** syncronized to the peer.

**Question:** Should changes caused by OMAPI operations be syncronzed between 2 DHCP servers in a failover configuration the way leases are? If not, should I deal with this by simply making the same changes on both servers? I don't want to do anything that might corrupt my leases file(s), etc.